# Lenovo TouchPad V15-IIL not working on Ubuntu 21.04

Tags: grub2, upgrade, touchpad, lenovo, 21.04

On my Lenovo V15-II my touchpad didnt work. The workaroung down there fixed it for me in 20.04. Upgraded to 21.04 and same happens, but this fix isnt working now. Does someone got the same issue and fixed it?

Does someone made a fresh install and it worked with this fix again?

Run

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

and append `i8042.nopnp=1 pci=nocrs` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`, so that the line will be:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash i8042.nopnp=1 pci=nocrs"
```

Then save the file and run in a terminal

```
sudo update-grub
```

Reboot, and the touchpad should work.
Source is https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1881322

Comment: I am having the same problem in ubuntu 22.04 LTS. The above fix worked in 20.04 LTS but its not working in 22.04 LTS.

Answer (score 0):

I've suffered with this problem for a couple of months, and it didn't work for me on 22.04 on an Ideapad 3 15iil05, until now!

I used that exact Grub command line

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash i8042.nopnp=1 pci=nocrs"
```

I had tried using it several times before and it left my machine unable to boot up.  Each time I had to edit Grub during the boot process in order to get up and running again.  I had to revert to "quiet splash".

This time it worked for me, and I think the key might have been installing build-essential before using update-grub.  So, try this before running the steps above and it might work for you:

```
sudo apt install build-essential -y
```

Hope it works for you!